# AppEngine Discounted Instance Hour disappeared?

Tags: google-app-engine

I cannot find the configuration for Discounted Instance Hour under Billing Status any more?  Is that functionality moved else where?  (Billing is enabled, and Maximum Daily Budget is also available.  I was just setting it a couple of weeks ago.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pricing of Google App Engine was 0.08$/instance hour and with discount was for 0.05$/instance hour. They reduced all the pricing to 0.05$ and removed Discounted Instance Hour concept. (It was actually very hard to predict how much instance hours you needed each month)

You can check the [new pricing here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing)

Or you can use the [pricing calculator for all of Google Cloud Platform products](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/)